# How to show error view after CSV export after directly writing to HttpContext.Current.Response?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, export-to-csv, response.redirect

In an ASP.NET MVC web application I write directly to HttpContext.Current.Response to export to a CSV file.

This is done in an action in my controller. So I do something like this:

```
try
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", fileName);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("a,b,c\n");
}
catch(Exception)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;

    return RedirectToAction("Error");
    //return PartialView("ErrorExportingData"); //Prefered!

}
```

This works without any problem, except that the page is not redirected (or the partial view is not displayed). I guess the problem is that a complete response was already created (and completed).

I flush the response and suppress the content before the redirect, so the exception stack trace does not end up in my CSV file. After this I somehow need to build a new response.

My question is: In this situation, How can I redirect to an error page, after an exception was thrown?

(If somebody wonders why I want to write directly to HttpContext.Current.Response? This is because it is the fastest way to write many records to a CSV file, using a SqlDataReader.)

Comment: Well, considering that writing directly to the response is your problem here, I'd say any (probably neglible) performance gain is outweighed by the negative consequences. You could just as easily write to a memory stream and then send that as the response if it's successful, and I doubt it would be any less performant that writing directly to the response.

Comment: I have considered writing to a memory stream, but with millions of records it does not seem a very good idea to fill the servers memory with all this data.

Comment: What do you think is happening when you write to the response? It doesn't start sending anything to the client. It stores the response memory until it's returned.

Comment: @Chris Pratt: Not quite true I think. When you use HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false; it is immediately sent to the client.